# Different Uri for same File

Tags: android, uri, media, mediastore

Don't know why for the same file/gallery/emulator i get different uris every time i try to acces a file. I tried with a different project and these are the results i obtained.

1º ATTEMPT

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A32
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F32/ORIGINAL/NONE/1110013234
```

2º ATTEMPT

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A32
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F32/ORIGINAL/NONE/1735025417
```

As you see, in the second project i get different uri every time i try to access the same file.The type of file is video and also I'm looking for help to implement FileProvider to my project, any help?

Comment: Please show us how are you accessing that file - share your code

Comment: This is quite normal. It depends on the way the user browses in the the gui for for instance Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Like going to VIDEOS or first to google photos app.